# Can't get this simple python program to work

Tags: python

I'm learning how to program in Python and got stuck on this simple exercise. I saved the code below to a file, test.py and ran it from my OSX command line using "python test.py" and keep getting an error message that I can't understand. My guess that the error is some fairly obvious thing that was overlooked :P

The error message follows the code:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
  return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
  if city == "Charlotte":
    return 183
  elif city == "Tampa":
    return 220
  elif city == "Pittsburgh":
    return 222
  elif city == "Los Angeles":
    return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
  total = 40 * days
  if days >= 7:
    total = total - 50
  elif days >= 3:
    total = total - 20
  return total

def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
  return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + 
  spending_money

thecity = raw_input("What city will you visit? ")
thedays = raw_input("How many days will you be traveling? ")
thespending_money = raw_input("How much spending money will you have? ")

trip_cost(thecity, thedays, thespending_money)
```

The console error message:

```
$ python test.py
What city will you visit? Los Angeles
How many days will you be traveling? 5
How much spending money will you have? 600
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
  trip_cost(thecity, thedays, thespending_money)
File "test.py", line 23, in trip_cost
  return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + spending_money
File "test.py", line 17, in rental_car_cost
  total = total - 50
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: The error is obvious.  You are trying to _add_ string and an integer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This works differently from C++'s input/output streams.

Comment: try to cast your "thedays" and "thespending_money" variables to int via int(variable_name)

Comment: @JIL When using C++ streams you specifically declare variable types. Python can't guess that you need an integer. Maybe you need a float, or complex, or string? So string is returned, and it needs to be converted to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Change `thedays = raw_input("How many days will you be traveling? ")` into `thedays = input("How many days will you be traveling? ")`, and replace all other `raw_input` with `input` whenever you need a numerical value.

Comment: -1. Using `input` is a bad idea, since it can run arbitrary code. It is a much better idea to use an appropriate call, such as `int`. This automatic-eval behaviour was removed in Python 3 for just this reason.

Answer (score 1):

Afrer `thecity = raw_input("What city will you visit? ")` "thecity" is a string. Make integer from string with `int`:

```
thecity = int(raw_input("What city will you visit? "))
```

Similarly for other inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
thedays = raw_input("How many days will you be traveling? ")
```

`raw_input` returns a string. So, when you enter `5`, you get the *string* `'5'` rather than the *integer* `5`. Python does not automatically convert these for you when you try to add them, since that can lead to bigger surprises in some cases. Instead, it wants you to do the conversion explicitly, so that your code is always unambiguous in the case of *any* input (eg, "parse the string 'abc' as a base 10 integer" is *always* an error; trying to do `"abc" + 5` via implicit conversion might decide to turn 5 into the string '5' and do string concatenation to give `"abc5"`).

The way to do this is with the builtin `int`, which takes a string and gives you back an integer parsed from it:

```
thedays = int(raw_input("How many days will you be traveling? "))
```